# IBM RAD 8.0 Datasource Connectivity

Tags: ibm-rad

Problem
In RAD 8.0 (installed on local work station), we have configured the datasource to connect to DB2 on Iseries.
The test operation in web console of RAD, was successful with 2 warnings.

However, when tried to connect from application (programmatically), we are getting following exception

java.lang.Class.throwNoSuchMethodException:
J2CA0009E: An exception occurred while trying to instantiate the ManagedConnectionFactory 
class com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSManagedConnectionFactoryImpl used by resource 
jdbc/iSeries_Conn : java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.ibm.ejs.j2c.DefaultSecurityHelper.
(javax.resource.spi.ManagedConnectionFactory, com.ibm.ejs.j2c.MCFExtendedProperties)

Steps followed

1. JDBC Provider chosen while setting up provider driver : DB2 UDB for iSeries (Toolbox XA)
2. Driver library used: jt400.jar (We have picked from IBM’s dev studio)
3. Created Datasource, when tested, the connection was successful with 2 warnings

   a.    warning : The property 'translateBoolean' does not exist on the DataSource class com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCXADataSource.

   b.    warning : The property 'metaDataSource' does not exist on the DataSource class com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCXADataSource.
4. Programmatically tried to access the datasource, with following statement

   a.    Context ctx = new InitialContext();

   b.    db2DataSource = (DataSource) ctx.lookup(“jdbc/iSeries_Conn”); //Exception occurs at this line

Can you please suggest an appropriate solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with a connector jar (iwdtrt.jar ) file that was superseding jt400.jar and hence The classes in jt400.jar were suppressed.

This issues is resolved by removing iwdtrt.jar file from the web lib folder.